# how to call one object from another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

please help to fix the script.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox


class Operations():
    def new(self, parent):
        global workArea

        if workArea == True:
            tkinter.messagebox.showwarning('Warning', 'New document is already open')
        else:    
            self.new = WorkArea(parent)
            workArea = True      

    def openFile(self):
        global workArea

        if workArea == True:
            tkinter.messagebox.showwarning('Warning', 'Close the open document')
        else:
            try:
                nameOpenFile = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(title = 'Open textPad file', filetypes=[("textPad files", "*.tpd")])
            except Exception:
                pass
            else:
                try:
                    pointerFileOpened = open(nameOpenFile, 'rt')
                except Exception:
                    tkinter.messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Open file error')
                else:
                    self.new(root)
                    self.readFile(pointerFileOpened)
                finally:                        
                    pointerFileOpened.close()

    def readFile(self, pointerFileOpened):
        while True:
            line = pointerFileOpened.readline()
            if len(line) == 0:
                break
            else:
                self.new.insert(tkinter.END, line)  #this is problem line
        return


class WorkArea(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent  
        self.makeWorkArea()

    def makeWorkArea(self):
        self.parent.title("My default workarea")

        workArea = tkinter.Text(self.parent)
        workArea.pack(expand = 'yes', fill = 'both')


class ToolBar(Operations, tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent  
        self.makeToolBar()

    def makeToolBar(self):
        frame = tkinter.Frame(self.parent)
        frame.pack(side = 'top', fill = 'x')

        tool1 = tkinter.Button(frame, text = 'New', command = lambda: self.new(root))
        tool1.pack(side = 'left')

        tool2 = tkinter.Button(frame, text = 'Open', command = lambda: self.openFile())
        tool2.pack(side = 'left')


workArea = False

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry('900x500+200+100')
toolBar = ToolBar(root)
root.mainloop()
```

after the user opens tpd-file should be output to the screen the contents of the file. but instead I get an error message:

> File "C:\Python33\projects\TEXTPADS\textPad_OOP\q.py", line 32, in
>   openFile
>       self.readFile(pointerFileOpened)   File "C:\Python33\projects\TEXTPADS\textPad_OOP\q.py", line 42, in readFile
>       self.new.insert(tkinter.END, line) AttributeError: 'WorkArea' object has no attribute 'insert'

Comment: Your `WorkArea` class is a `Frame`. Did you mean to make it a `Text`? Or did you mean `workArea.insert`? Your class structure is very strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the "WorkArea" object is an instance of the tkinter `Frame` class, and this class doesn't define a method or attribute named "insert".

In the definition of the `WorkArea` class, you define a local variable named `workArea` that holds a reference to a text widget. It appears you're wanting to insert data into this text widget. In order to do that, you need to a) make `workArea` (the local variable) be an instance variable, and then either call the `insert` method of this object, or create an `insert` method in your `WorkArea` class.

For example, to directly call the `workArea` attribute:

```
class Operations():
    ...
    def readFile(self, pointerFileOpened):
        ...
        self.new.workArea.insert(...)
        ...

class WorkArea(...):
   ...
    def makeWorkArea(self):
        ...
        self.workArea = tkinter.Text(self.parent)
        ...
```

To create an `insert` method in the `WorkArea` class:

```
class Operations():
    ...
    def readFile(self, pointerFileOpened):
        ...
        self.new.insert(...)
        ...

class WorkArea(...):
   ...
    def makeWorkArea(self):
        ...
        self._text = tkinter.Text(self.parent)
        ...

    def insert(self, *args):
        '''act as a proxy to the internal text widget'''
        self._text.insert(*args)
```

The second solution is arguably the better solution. The `Operations` class shouldn't know that the `WorkArea` class has an internal widget with a specific name. This *tightly couples* the two classes together: you can't change `WorkArea` without also changing `Operations`.

By creating your own `insert` function you are creating a contract, where `WorkArea` is promising to insert text somewhere, but the caller doesn't need to know where. This results in a *loose coupling*. You are free to change `WorkArea` all you want -- rename the widget, use a different widget, etc. -- without having to modify the `Operations` class. That is, assuming that you don't violate the contract and remove the `insert` function from `WorkArea`.

On a related note: you should avoid using the same or similar names for so many things. At one point you have a class named `WorkArea`, a variable named `WorkArea` that you set to True or False, and a local variable named `workArea`. This makes your code very hard to understand.